# What does a[c - 'a' ]++ mean in Java?

Tags: java, string, foreach

The goal is to count the common characters in two strings and return an integer. I understand everything except

```
a[c - 'a' ]++;
```

I've tried searching through a few classes's documentation, googling whats in quotations, and googling a few possible descriptions for what is happening, but I am unable to even find out what to call `a[c - 'a' ]++;` let alone what it's actually doing. To me it seems it's counting an occurrence of a particular char but I am uncertain.

Here's the code

```
int commonCharacterCount(String s1, String s2) {
int[] a = new int[26], 
    b = new int[26];
for (char c: s1.toCharArray())
    a[c - 'a']++;
for (char c: s2.toCharArray())
    b[c - 'a']++;
int s = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) 
    s +=Math.min(a[i],b[i]);
return s;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'a'` is of type `char` which - coming from a C tradition - can be interpreted as [a number type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). That is, you can do arithmetic with it just like with `int` or `long`.

The value of a `char` is traditionally given by the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) where `'a'` happens to be the same as `97`.

In your code, `c` is also a `char`, and if you assume `s1` and `s2` to only contain lower-case letters, you know that `c` is somewhere in the range `[97,122]`. Subtracting `'a'` (i.e., `97`) from that then gives you the more convenient range `[0,25]` to work with.

I say "more convenient" because here, `c - 'a'` is used to index the array `a`, and as you know, array indices start at 0.

Comment: The value of `char` is given by UTF-16 where ASCII is a subset.

Comment: Correct, but note that I wrote "traditionally" which was more aimed to point at the origin of this convention.

Comment: @Thomas thank you! I knew char had numeric values but I was failing to understand how subtracting 'a'  from the current index determined which element in the array to increment, I understand now it's simplifying the char's numeric value down.

Comment: @TylerRoberson - That's because your not actually subtracting from the current index: you're subtracting from the current *character*. That is, c is not `0, 1, 2, ...` but it is `s1[0], s1[1], s1[2],...` (or the same for `s2`) Well, I'm mixing Strings and array notation here, but you get my drift.

Answer (score 3):

Characters in Java can be manipulated as small integers in some contexts. The expression `c - 'a'` means "the integer representation of `c`" minus "the integer representation of `'a'`". In other words, you're getting the offset of `c` with respect to `'a'` in the ASCII character set, i.e., the index of `c` in the lowercase alphabet.

Thus `a[c - 'a']++` means increment the counter in `a` with index `i`, where `i` is the position of `c` in the alphabet.

Comment: I like this explanation better than my own.